# How to prevent duplicate time entries on datagridview using VB. NET and MySQL as database

Tags: mysql, vb.net, linq, if-statement, datagridview

I need a little help on my scheduling system using VB. NET and MySQL as database.  The problem is how can I prevent duplicate time entries on datagridview for instance I put 7:00AM to 9:00AM and if you input another time entries it should be cannot input time between 7:00AM to 9:00AM. Thank you guys appreciate your little help regards! Here's my code:

```
    Try

        MysqlConn.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "insert into school.schedule
            (schedid, roomid, prof_id, subjectid, day, start_time, end_time, mode, classid, school_year, sem)
            values ('" & schedidtxt.Text & "', '" & roomidtxt.Text & "',
            '" & profidtxt.Text & "', '" & subjectidtxt.Text & "', '" & daycombobox.Text & "', 
            '" & fromcombobox.Text & "', '" & tocombobox.Text & "', '" & modecombobox.Text & "',
            '" & classidtxt.Text & "', '" & schoolyeartxt.Text & "', '" & semtxt.Text & "')"
        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
        READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader

        MessageBox.Show("Data Saved")
        MysqlConn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Dispose()

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Never, ever concat strings to make SQL.  Your code doesnt show a DataGridView involved at all.

Comment: base on your question, before you insert, check if that data already exist to prevent duplicates. There is so many reference you can find in net.